# Trying not to create new file every second but if file limit exceed then create new file using log4net

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I am trying to create file with naming convention as `Service_HH_mm_ss.txt`.

file naming format is

`<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\\Log\\%date{yyyy-MM-dd}\\Service_%date{HH_mm_ss}.log" />`

Also i have given file max size to

```
<rollingStyle value="Size" />      
<maximumFileSize value="10KB" />
```

**i want to create new file if and only if size exceed to 10KB, but new file is getting  creating on each and every second.**

not able to find the solution.

Config file code is:
`<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\\Log\\%date{yyyy-MM-dd}\\Service_%date{HH_mm_ss}.log" />

      <encoding value="utf-8" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="20" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10KB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="false" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
         <conversionPattern value="%date %level - %message%n" />
      </layout>`

Is it possible to do what i want, i ma not getting any solution.

Answer (score 2):

In your Appender definition the value for the File name changes every second. Therefor log4net creates a new file every second. If you need the exact time to be part of the file name, you can use rolling Style 'Composite' and add a DatePattern like so:

```
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\\Log\\%date{yyyy-MM-dd}\\Service_" />

  <encoding value="utf-8" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
  <datePattern value = "HH_mm_ss'.log'"
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="20" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10KB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
     <conversionPattern value="%date %level - %message%n" />
  </layout>
```

Comment: still i am getting same problem. new file created on each and every second.