# log4net RollingFileAppender is not rolling by date every second

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

I am using log4net to log files with a RollingFileAppender currently set to roll on both file size and date (Composite). Currently the date pattern is set such that it will roll every day. Instead I would like it to roll every second.

I have been able to modify the date pattern however somehow the smallest roll I can get is down to the minute. I think my datepattern is right, as it applies correct to the file name down to the second (or even millisecond, even though I only post outcome for the second level here). However the roll only happens on the next full minute.

Here is my configuration for the appender :

```
type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{LogFilePath}Prog.csv" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
        <datePattern value="dd-MM-yyy_HHmmss" />
        <PreserveLogFIlenameExtension value="true" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="100" />
        <ImmediateFlush value="true"/>
        <maximumFileSize value="2MB" />
        <staticLogFileName value="false" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <header value="[Date], [Time], [Thread], [Component], [Group], [Purpose], [Msg]&#13;&#10;"/>
          <footer value="[Date], [Time], [Thread], [Component], [Group], [Purpose], [Msg]&#13;&#10;"/>
          <conversionPattern value="%d{[dd/MM/yyyy], [HH:mm:ss.fff]}, [%thread], %message%newline" />
        </layout>
</appender>
```

And I get files something as follow:

- Prog.11-01-2020_004752.csv
- Prog.11-01-2020_004752.1.csv
- Prog.11-01-2020_004752.2.csv
- Prog.11-01-2020_004800.csv
- Prog.11-01-2020_004800.1.csv
- Prog.11-01-2020_004800.2.csv
- Prog.11-01-2020_004900.csv
- Prog.11-01-2020_004900.1.csv
- Prog.11-01-2020_004900.2.csv

So I started at 00h47m52s which created a log file which rolled because of max size reached twice, then it rolled again on the next full minute at 00h48m00s (which rolled because of max size reached twice) and at 00h49m00s, 00h50m00s, etc.

Is that a known issue or am I doing something wrong ? I have not found anything online after lots of search. The only thing I found is the following post:

[Trying not to create new file every second but if file limit exceed then create new file using log4net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54688474/trying-not-to-create-new-file-every-second-but-if-file-limit-exceed-then-create)

They were reporting that their config file *did* roll every second which they wanted to avoid. Surely enough they were using a date pattern containing seconds and it behaved the way I would like it to work. So it really appears that the issue is not with the pattern I use. This is very puzzling.

Any clue or lead very welcome!

Comment: Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4net/blob/master/src/Appender/RollingFileAppender.cs), it seems that the smallest rolling interval is 1 minute (RollPoint.TopOfMinute). It you need faster rolling, you could write your own appender.

Comment: Yes I can see that now, the enum start at 0 for minutes so that's clearly the minimum possible. Maybe they should make that clear in the documentation. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe they couldn’t see a use case for rolling every second - and neither can I. What’s yours?

Comment: I needed it because I also had a roll over on size and a great number of log entries made it difficult to find a particular time where the things I was looking for correlating from another log file happened. Down to the second, based on the file name I can just open the correct file. I coded my own appender to achieve that.